# how does TFS's shelveset model compare to a DVCS?

Tags: tfs, dvcs

Let's say a person is working in a small team SCRUM environment. Several teams are working on different branches of the same code base. In our team we usually split up into pairs to work on code. Occasionally people need to take time off etc. and it would be advantageous to be able to merge person A's code into person B's codebase. But they often don't want to commit at the end of the day for fear of breaking the build.

This led me to **DVCS** -- well suited to P2P merging and doesn't require "the big commit". A team member suggested that TFS's **shelveset** would be able to do this as well. **How do the two approaches compare?**

Team is currently using Subversion.

Comment: Don't have time for a whole answer, but subjectively my opinion as a git and TFS user is that shelvesets are weak sauce for that kind of collaboration.

Comment: @jball: yeah, that was my opinion (uninformed) as well

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The TFS shelveset allows you to create something akin to a changeset, that isn't stored in the main repository. This shelveset is a backup, and can be "pulled" by another developer from another machine. This "private repository", and the ability to "pull" it is as far as the shelveset compares to DVCS. Shelvesets however are not true repositories; they are merely snapshots, they do not maintain history, and you cannot check in or manage changes as you would with the source control repository on your TFS.

A DVCS is a lot more than this; with a DVCS, you have a complete copy of the repository on your machine. You can commit locally as often as you want, storing each and every change you make; you can revert changes as much as you want, since your machine is for all intents and purposes, your source control.
And then you can push your changes to another machine (central repositor, build machine, or whatever). DVCS is a completely different and flexible paradigm, that allows but doesn't require the use of a central repository. It frees you of having to choose between stable and frequent check-ins (you can check-in locally whenever you want, and push when you're stable).

There's a lot more to it. If you like, you can checkout Joel Spolskey's excellent (and hillarious) intro to Mercurial DVCS at [hginit.com](http://hginit.com/).

Hope this helps,
Assaf.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tfs-git solution. Git will allow you to do what you want, shape it to how you want the changes to read, then commit to tfs at the end of the day.

I would recommend switching to git anyway.

Comment: Your answer is confusing to me since it doesn't mention shelvesets at all. Git isn't an option because there's no plugin for Visual Studio. I'm looking at Mercurial.

Comment: Git extensions. Also, you can map external tools. I suggest NOT using VCS through the IDE. Git stash is very light weight, robust and flexible.

Comment: Also, the local commits can be shaped to the way you want and extra local branches managed eliminating for the need to shelve at all in the first place. There are many reasons that Git is very popular - this is just one among many.

Comment: I still don't think you've actually compared *TFS* shelvesets to dvcs at all. You've just explained why I wouldn't need shelvesets if I used dvcs.

Comment: True. How much detail do you need? For example, when you delete a shelveset in TFS, it is permanent. In git, when you pop the stash, the reflog still exists and even if it wasn't there, you can get your data back. Unless you go out of your way to force the repository to drop those items.

Comment: The comparison is not really needed in the end. The stash in git does what shelve sets do in tfs and much better.